# how do i get the coordinates of a shape in fabric js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, svg, fabricjs

I tried the following code snippet but I am getting undefined in alert where I am accessing as thisCoords.t1 , can any one please guide me?

```
<!--fabric js function to get coordinates of active object-->
    function getCoords(oCoords) {
        return {
          tl: new fabric.Point(oCoords.tl.x, oCoords.tl.y),
          tr: new fabric.Point(oCoords.tr.x, oCoords.tr.y),
          bl: new fabric.Point(oCoords.bl.x, oCoords.bl.y),
          br: new fabric.Point(oCoords.br.x, oCoords.br.y)
        }
      }

<!--fabric js mouse move event-->
    canvas.on('mouse:move', function(e){
    console.log('over1',e.target)
    if(e.target && e.target !== canvas.getActiveObject())
     canvas.setActiveObject(e.target)
     var thisCoords = getCoords(canvas.getActiveObject().oCoords);
     alert("coords :"+thisCoords.t1);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getCoords` function is returning an object with keys `tl, tr, bl, br`. You are trying to access key `t1` which is surely a typo. Simply replace `alert("coords :"+thisCoords.t1);` with `alert("coords :"+thisCoords.tl);`